# Remove null values in MySQL and combine non null values into one cell

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello guys? I have a MySQL table storing timetable classes, a specific subject is allocated to a specific timeslot stored in columns. I have no issue when there are no two subjects taught at the same time since I use max() to select from the time table i.e
[image: table dd]

```
Select dayid,max(`1`) as `1` ,
 max(`2`) as `2` ,
 max(`4`) as `4` ,
 max(`5`) as `5` ,
 max(`7`) as `7` ,
 max(`8`) as `8` ,
 max(`10`) as `10` ,
 max(`11`) as `11` ,
 max(`13`) as `13` ,
 max(`14`) as `14` 
 FROM  dd GROUP BY dd.days ORDER BY dayid
```

The above query gives me this results
[image: Result from query]

Now from the first image you can see that the highlighted rows have the same dayid and same timeslot which means they are taught at the same time but my query will only give me one subject (KISW F1A)

I want to achieve this (KISW F1A/BIO F1A) in the cells where classes are taught at the same time.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, i.e. not as images.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the heads up, I thought the image is well presented with an exact problem I was dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_concat()`

```
Select dayid,group_concat(`1`) as `1` ,
 group_concat(`2`) as `2` ,
 group_concat(`4`) as `4` ,
 group_concat(`5`) as `5` ,
 group_concat(`7`) as `7` ,
 group_concat(`8`) as `8` ,
 group_concat(`10`) as `10` ,
 group_concat(`11`) as `11` ,
 group_concat(`13`) as `13` ,
 group_concat(`14`) as `14` 
 FROM  dd GROUP BY dd.days ORDER BY dayid
```